# Dropzone: Binding to init

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js, jquery-events

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/dropzonejs-php-how-to-display-existing-files-on-server) on mocking existing files to a Dropzone enabled form, but am having trouble hooking onto the `init` function. Here's what I have so far:

```
var imageUpload;

if ($('.js-listing__images-upload').length) {
  imageUpload = new Dropzone('.js-listing__images-upload', {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 3,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif'
  });
  imageUpload.on('init', function() {
    var listingID, thisDropzone;
    console.log('dropzone init');
    thisDropzone = this;
    listingID = $('#manage-images').data('listing');
    $.ajax({
      url: dashboard.images.list,
      data: {
        listing: listingID
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('ajax for list done');
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          var mockFile;
          mockFile = {
            name: value.name,
            size: value.size
          };
          thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
          thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, '/uploads/thumb/listings/' + value.name);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

None of my `console.log()` fire, but I'm unsure as to what the issue could be. Following Dropzone's config, I should be able to hook onto events using simple `on` mechanisms. Thanks all!

## Update

The following does work:

```
# When images are removed
# Dropzone
imageUpload.on 'removedfile', (file) ->
  if file.xhr
    imageID = JSON.parse file.xhr.response
    $.ajax
      url: dashboard.images.destroy
      data: { image: imageID }
      success: () ->
  return
```

So it's something about the `init` function that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: What is `$('.js-listing__images-upload').length` evaluating to? Also, is the DOM ready when you run this code? Is this in your `$(function(){//Code here})`?

Comment: Hi @arjabbar the check I have for `.js-listing__images-upload` is evaluating to true; so we're good there. I have everything wrapped in a self-envoking anonymous function. Any issues with using that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `init` function can be binded directly to your new Dropzone instantiation:

```
if $('.js-listing__images-upload').length
  imageUpload = new Dropzone(
    '.js-listing__images-upload',
    addRemoveLinks: true
    maxFiles: 5
    maxFilesize: 3
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif'
    init: ->
      thisDropzone = this
      $.ajax
        url: dashboard.images.list
        data: { listing: $('#manage-images').data('listing') }
        success: (data) ->
          $.each data, (key, value) ->
            mockFile =
              name: value.name
              size: value.size
            thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call thisDropzone, mockFile
            thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call thisDropzone, mockFile, '/uploads/thumb/listings/' + value.name
            return
          return
      return
  )
```